# Exporting Application Model from SP Designer 2010 to Visual Studio 2010 BDC Model Project

Tags: bcs, bdc-model

I've created an Application Model in SP Designer 2010 and exported it (XML file).  I'd like to use the definition in a Business Data Connectivity Project in Visual Studio 2010.

Is there a way to create a project and import the model?  It seems like an easy way to create the model then be able to package the model in a solution and deploy with the new VS 2010 F5 functionality.

An added note to this problem is that the data is accessible through stored procs so the BCS Meta Man in it's Alpha build won't help us out.

Answer (score 1):

you can copy and paste the XML model from SharePoint Designer into the VS model file if you open it in an XML editor. It will be exactly the same as the SPD one though so you'd need to make quite a few changes to call code methods instead of SQL queries.

If you try out BCS Meta Man:

[BCS Meta Man](http://www.lightningtools.com/bcs/bcs-meta-man.aspx)

You can open a model created in SharePoint Designer and it will generate the c# methods and model required for you. Here's a blog post that shows it in action:

[Upgrade SPD models into .Net Assembly Connector](http://www.lightningtools.com/blog/archive/2010/05/17/open-bcs-model-created-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-in-visual.aspx)

Hope this helps
Nick

Comment: Nick, the BCS Meta Man tool is great but at present doesn't play well with stored procs.  We only use stored procedures as it adds additional security and optional coding flexibility.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the feedback, we'll bump stored procs up our development schedule. If you have any other feedback about the tool please feel free to post it in the forums or shoot me an email http://connect.lightningtools.com/default.aspx?action=ViewTopics&fid=2